# SQLite Entity Framework Azure App sqlite3_blob_open does not have an implementation

Tags: sqlite, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-web-app-service

> TLDR; I'm getting an error when reading from **SQLite**
>   database deployed to **Azure webb app**. Works fine locally..
>
> TypeLoadException: Method 'sqlite3_blob_open' in type
>   'SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3' from assembly
>   'SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=9c301db686d0bd12' does not have an implementation.

I use the following technologies

- **SQLite for EntityFrameworkCore**
- **Asp.Net Core**
- **Azure web app, free service plan**
- **Project created from React.js template in Visual Studio 2017**

[image]

**It works locally but when I deploy it to the Azure web app I get the following error when trying to read data from the database.**

[image]

In my startup.cs I have the following

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=appDatabase.db"));
}
```

AppDbContext.cs

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Persons> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

My SQLite database file "appDatabase.db" is placed directly in the web projects folder next to the startup.cs

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The issue was fixed after adding another nuget package called **SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3**

https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw

[image: https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw]

I found this thread https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/567 that mentioned some sort of bundle package so I searched nuget and found this.